# How to use if-else in google sheets with currency?

Tags: google-sheets

I have an issue where I am trying to make a comparison between values to see if A contains value then use that value and if B contains the value then use that value, something like this:
[image: Google sheet]

My goal is that when I have resell pris (SEK) value, then I should just `=SUM(O6-I6)` in `Totala profit` but if I have in EURO then I want to convert the currency from euro to todays currency in SEK and calculate that for totala profit, meaning something like `(100€ * swedish currency) - value in totala profit e.g. 1000.`

My question is, is it possible to do that using google sheet? if so, how can I use the if else statement for that?

Expected:

Should take Resell pris SEK/EUR - totala profit depending on where we have the value. If we have in SEK then we do Resell pris SEK - Totala profit and if we have EURO then convert to SEK and then - totala profit.

Actual:

I only managed to make it work if there is a value in Resell pris (SEK)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `if()` and `regexmatch()`, like this:

`=(O6 - I6) * if( regexmatch(to_text(O6), "(?i)EUR|€"), R$1, 1 )`

...where cell `R1` gets the exchange rate with `googlefinance()`, like this:

`=googlefinance("EURSEK")`

Comment: Oh wow this was it! Appreciate that alot!